# SQL Subquery just return one value.How Can make this code efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select count(*) as CountId, [FirstRouteNo],[ThroughRouteSid],[LastRouteNo],
       (select top 1 [ThroughRouteJson]
        from DirectTransfer as Subquery
        where MainQuery.FirstRouteNo=Subquery.FirstRouteNo and
              MainQuery.ThroughRouteSid = Subquery.ThroughRouteSid and
              MainQuery.LastRouteNo = Subquery.LastRouteNo
       ) as DetailJson,
       (select top 1 RouteMeter
        from DirectTransfer as Subquery 
        where MainQuery.FirstRouteNo = Subquery.FirstRouteNo and
              MainQuery.ThroughRouteSid = Subquery.ThroughRouteSid and
              MainQuery.LastRouteNo = Subquery.LastRouteNo
       ) as RouteMeter
from DirectTransfer as MainQuery                                    
group by MainQuery.[FirstRouteNo],MainQuery.[ThroughRouteSid],MainQuery.[LastRouteNo]
order by CountId desc
```

I want to group by this column [FirstRouteNo],[ThroughRouteSid],[LastRouteNo] then Count How many records.but I also want to show two column values like [ThroughRouteJson] and [RouteMeter] any one of records.Because [ThroughRouteJson] and [RouteMeter] of value has little different.So I can't group by with them.then subquery only return one value.So I write two Subquery to get what I want.because my DB table has More than 100 million records.I want to make efficient. How can I make this code become more efficient then I can get the same result data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you do this as:

```
select dt.*, dt2.DetailJson, dt2.RouteMeter
from (select count(*) as cnt, dt.FirstRouteNo, dt.ThroughRouteSid, dt.LastRouteNo
      from DirectTransfer dt                               
      group by dt.FirstRouteNo, dt.ThroughRouteSid, dt.LastRouteNo
     ) dt outer apply
     (select top 1 ThroughRouteJson as DetailJson, RouteMeter
      from DirectTransfer dt2
      where dt.FirstRouteNo = dt.FirstRouteNo and
            dt.ThroughRouteSid = dt.ThroughRouteSid and
            dt.LastRouteNo = dt.LastRouteNo
     ) dt2
order by CountId desc;
```

You want indexes on `DirectTransfer(FirstRouteNo, ThroughRouteSid, LastRouteNo)`.  There might be other ways to accomplish what you want, but it is a bit unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know How it work. your code like left join right? but outer apply if you have 
one column is null. The result will return nothing..That is left join and outer apply different?

Comment: How I can I change this code to left join? because column is [RouteMeter] possibility null.but I need show all the data...

Comment: @LeonHuang . . . This answers your question.  Why would you want to use `left join`?

Comment: I mixed up between outer apply and cross apply.Because my column [RouteMeter]  value possible null.but no matter [RouteMeter] is null or not null.I want to show every record.I try your method.It's perfect. I really appreciate.